# How to validate 2 inputs using form_validate that using 1 data field?

Tags: php

I have this 2 form validation that validating 2 inputs that actually will go to 1 data field in db named kode_bthp like this :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('kode_bthp', 'Kode Barang', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nup', 'NUP', 'required|trim');

$data = ['kode_bthp' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('kode_bthp', true) . $this->input->post('nup', true))];
```

the problem is I can't using *is_unique* feature because that 2 will be always unique (because not joined) and this data is not primary data so it will be inputted even it has same value.

then I tried something like this to join it first before get validated

```
$kd_bthpjoined = $this->input->post('kode_bthp') . $this->input->post('nup');

$this->form_validation->set_rules($kd_bthpjoined, 'Kode Barang', 'required|trim|is_unique[bthp_master.kode_bthp]', ['is_unique' => 'Code Already Registered']);
```

question is, using variable `$kd_bthpjoined` can make it work ? because I tried to run it and didnt shows anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try make custom form validation using **form validation callback**, you can check on codeigniter documentation.

like this example :

```
$ini = this->input->('kode_bthp'), true). $this->input->post('nup', true));

$this->load->model('model_name');
$query = $this->menu_model->getBthp($ini)

if(count($query)>0){
 //then . . . .
}else{
 return true;
}
```